# Django : how to extract items of another table from one table if they are related by foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two tables : **User** and **Details**(which includes details of books).They are linked with each other by a foreign key as shown:

```
class Details(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)
    BName= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    BPublisher= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    BEdition= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    BAuthor= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    BClass= models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now i need to extract all the books from the table-Details posted by distinct user. How can I do this ? The Filed in Django admin looks like :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpsFN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in your view function:

```
def get_book_set(request):
   user_instance = request.user
   book_set = Details.objects.filter(user = user_instance)
   context = {'user':user_instance, 'book_set':book_set}
   return render(request, 'template_file.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

let

```
 u = User.objects.get(id=your_id)
```

you can get books of user u by django reverse relation:

```
book_set = u.details_set.all()
```

you can change default related_name details_set (ModelName_set) in you model:

```
user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, related_name='book')
```